# React Native build looks for sdk licenses in wrong folder

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile, android-sdk-tools

I am currently trying to build my react native app in the CLI and it's giving me this error

```
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses       
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
     emulator Android Emulator
     platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
     build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
     tools Android SDK Tools
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

But then I realize that the build was actually looking in the wrong directory and this could be why it's giving me the license error. My licenses are located in `android-sdk` but the build is looking for the licenses in `android-sdk/platform-tools` which I do also have.

```
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\licenses       
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.
```

How do I reconfigure the build to look to the right directory? Can I just drag the license folder to the platform tools folder? would this be safe or not?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should specify the folder.
Go to the android/ directory of your project;
Create a file named local.properties containing this:
sdk.dir = D:\Android\android-sdk

Comment: I tried this, still has the same error. The problem is not the sdk directory but rather the behavior of the license checking on build. It tries to look for licenses inside the platform-tools directory which is the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I cut-pasted the platform-tools under another platform-tools directory in my sdk directory since it was looking for it there. I also placed the license folder one folder above the 2nd platform-tools directory.